# Honoring A Recall

Tags: electrical, headlight, wiring, suzuki

I recently bought a 2005 Suzuki Reno and have been having some headlight problems. I noticed that there was a recall on them (for headlight problems) back in 2007 and again in August 2012.

The CarFax does not show that the previous owner ever fixed them.

Will the dealer still fix it free of charge? If not, could I fix it myself?

Comment: They *should* honor them. The easiest way to find out is to call the dealership and ask them. They will check your VIN against their database to see if the recalls had ever been done. If they haven't, you should be golden, but don't assume the recalls will fix *your* problems.

Comment: Well, my problem exactly matches what was recalled.

Who handles this anyways? Doesn't Subaru own Suzuki?

Comment: It very well could fix it, I was just suggesting you not *assume* it will fix it.

Comment: You can check for a service center near you by using [this website](http://www.suzukiauto.com/Service%20Provider.aspx) if in the US.

Comment: So there's a chance they will honor the recall?

Comment: I would (and have) answered yes to that, but don't know for sure. The only way to know is to call them.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to recalls 07V452000 and 12V397000, right?

If the recall has not expired, a dealer should perform the fix without charging you.  The only way to know for sure is to contact a Suzuki Dealer or Suzuki and ask.  The Dealer should be able to look the VIN up and give you a definitive answer as to whether the fix was applied to your vehicle.

Even if the recall has expired, the parts for the fix should be available as a kit that the dealer parts department will be happy to sell you.  If you go that route, shop around (multiple parts departments from different dealers and online if you can get the part number).